# "lottery" in javascript - sort algorithm?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm trying to understand the code example that's at the end of my post and I need help. So this is supposed to be a "lottery". So here's what I see:

```
for( i = 1 ; i < 50 ; i++ ){ nums[ i ] = i ; }
```

Here it assigns the value of i (which will be between 1 and 49) to each each i-th element of the nums array. So I guess it's just making an array that contains the numbers 1 to 49. I don't see the point of this whole line, actually, given the code that follows.

```
for( i = 1 ; i < 50 ; i++ )
 {
   rand = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 49 ) ;
   temp = nums[ i ] ;
   nums[ i ] = nums[ rand ] ;
   nums[ rand ] =temp ;
 }
```

---

Here I get confused. So, once again it runs a standard loop from 1 to 49, and for each of the 49 iterations, it:

1. assigns a random number between 1 and 49 to "rand"
2. assigns the i-th value of the 'nums' list (which will still be just i, right?) to temp (why?)
3. assigns the random number to the i-th element of the "nums" array, so presumably if it's at i=1, nums[i] = 1, and now instead of 1 it's the random number.
4. Then it assigns temp (which was the original value, which was i anyway) back to the value that's in the rand-th position of the nums array.

So what am I misunderstanding here? I don't get the point of this. Where is this leading? Am I reading it correctly? Presumably at the end of this, the numbers inside the array are jumbled up, and then at the end it just picks the first six, which are 6 "random" numbers. But why not just do something like:

```
var nums=[];
for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
  nums[i] == Math.ceil(Math.random() * 49);
}
```

along with a test to ensure the random numbers weren't the same?

---

Here's the code example in whole:

```
function init()
{
 var panel = document.getElementById( "panel" ) ;
 var i , rand , temp , str , nums = [] ;
 for( i = 1 ; i < 50 ; i++ ){ nums[ i ] = i ; }
 for( i = 1 ; i < 50 ; i++ )
 {
   rand = Math.ceil( Math.random() * 49 ) ;
   temp = nums[ i ] ;
   nums[ i ] = nums[ rand ] ;
   nums[ rand ] =temp ;
 }
 str = "Your Six Lucky Numbers:<br>" ;
 for( i = 1 ; i < 7 ; i++ )
 {
   str += nums[ i ] ;
   if( i !== 6 ) { str += " - " ; }
 }
 panel.innerHTML = str;
}
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded" , init , false ) ;
```

Comment: Your assumption at *2* is incorrect. Initially, the *i*th member will be *i*, but as the shuffle continues, it could be any of the available values since each *i* is swapped to a random position in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is supposed to create an array of numbers and then shuffle them. It's almost using a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), but not quite. There is also a bug in the random number generation.

Putting the numbers 1 through 49 in the array is not pointless, those are the numbers that are used later on. They are not replaced, they are just moved around in the array.

The next loop will shuffle the items in the array, but first let's look at the random number generation. This way of creating a random number is wrong:

```
rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 49); // Don't use this
```

The `Math.random()` method returns a value that is `0 <= x < 1`. Multiplying that number by 49 and then using `Math.ceil` doesn't produce numbers between 1 and 49, it produces numbers between 0 and 49. The number 0 comes very rarely, but you can't ignore it. The correct way to produce the random number is:

```
rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 49) + 1;
```

The code for shuffling the items in the array loops through the items and picks an item by random to swap each item with. This produces a biased shuffle, and it should use the Fisher-Yates algorithm instead:

```
for (i = 49 ; i >= 1 ; i--) {
  rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * i) + 1;
  temp = nums[i];
  nums[i] = nums[rand];
  nums[rand] = temp;
}
```

The last three lines in the loop swaps two items in the array. It stores away the value from one item, copies the value from the other item into the first, and then puts the stored value in the other item.

(The values of `i` and `rand` can actually be the same for some items, so that an item is swapped with itself. This is how the algorithm is supposed to work, it ensures that the item has the same chance of staying in the same place as the chance of being moved to any other place.)

> But why not just do something like [code] along with a test to ensure
>   the random numbers weren't the same?

That is another way of creating the random numbers. It would be somewhat more efficient, at least most of the time (it could theoretically loop forever), but it's about the same amount of code.

Another solution would be to put all the numbers in one array, then pick numbers by random from it and move them to another array. That is the same principle as the shuffling algorithm, but it only needs to shuffle enough to get the first six items in the right place (or the last six items as it would be using the Fisher-Yates algorithm). However, removing items from an array is generally an expensive operation, as the items after it needs to be shifted into its place.

Comment: The point about 0 being a possibility, understood. I did not understand why the sort from my example is biased, whereas if you do it basically the other way around (starting from 49 and counting down) it would be unbiased? Could you elaborate on what makes my example biased and yours not? Also, you explain that the 3 lines basically swap the numbers -- I see it; but I don't understand how that ensures that they are not repeated? I would appreciate some additional info on that! Thanks again!

Comment: @user3399551: The difference is that the Fisher-Yates algorithm only picks an item to the left (or the same item) instead of an item in the entire array. Notice the `* i` instead of `* 49` in the random number. On the page that I linked to about the Fisher-Yates algorithm is an explanation of why it's biased if you swap with any item in the array, in the section "Implementation errors". Regarding the numbers not being repeated; the array starts with the numbers 1 to 49, if you swap two of them it still has the numbers 1 to 49 only in a different order. There are no duplicates introduced.

Comment: OK, I finally got it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a basic shuffle. The point is to ensure we only have unique numbers to begin with.

Doing this shuffle iterates once over the loop.

Checking uniqueness requires iterating once over the loop... for every element in the loop.

For small loops like this, the difference is basically nil, but in general when given two options you should take the one that's less computationally complicated... but always remember to comment the code to explain it to future developers!